# JS regular expression to find a substring surrounded by double quotes

Tags: javascript

I need to find a substring surrounded by double quotes, for example, like `"test"`, `"te\"st"` or `""`, but not `"""` neither "\". To achieve this, which is the best way to go for it in the following

```
1) /".*"/g
2) /"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"/g
3) /"(?:\\?[\S\s])*?"/g
4) /"([^"\\]*("|\\[\S\s]))+/g
```

I was asked this question yesterday during an interview, and would like to know the answer for future reference.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you asking *us* a question someone has asked *you*, such as on a test or in a job interview. If so, you should *say* so.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was asked about this question yesterday during interview and had no idea how to answer. Now I want to know so it will help me in the future.

Comment: @x4ph4r: I notice you are frequently abandoning your questions, and leaving good answers unresponded to (like Gareth's below). Please look through your questions to see if any have garnered useful answers, consider ticking ones that solve the problem you had, and consider thanking them for their time.

Comment: @halfer thank you for turning my mind towards that. I will do it.

Comment: That's a fairly cruel whiteboard question. If it were me I'd use jsfiddle to test different possibilities while I lookup a regex reference. Answering cold at a whiteboard is pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These expressions evaluate as follows:

**Expression 1 matches:**

- An inverted comma
- Greedily any character, including an inverted comma or a slash
- A final inverted comma.

This would match `"test" some wrong text "text"`, and therefore fails

**Expression 2 matches:**

- An inverted comma
- Greedily as many characters that are not either an inverted comma or a slash
- Greedily as many sets of

  - Any chracter preceded by a slash
  - Greedily as many characters that are not either an inverted comma or a slash
- A final inverted comma

So this collects all chracters within the inverted commas in sets, broken by slashes. It specifically excludes an inverted comma if it is preceded by a slash by including it in any subsequent sets. This will work.

**Expression 3 matches:**

- An inverted comma
- As few sets as fit of:

  - Any one character preceded by an optional slash
- A final inverted comma

This collects all characters , optionally preceded by a slash, but not greedily. This will work

**Expression 4 matches:**

- An inverted comma
- Greedily all characters that are no either an inverted comma or a slash
- One or more of:

  - An inverted comma or
  - A slash and any character

This will match `"test"\x`, and therefore fails

**Conclusion:**

From what I can tell, both expressions 2 and 3 will work. I may have missed something, but both will certainly work (or not as appropriate) for the examples given. So the question, then, is which is better. I'd vote for three, because it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar is a little unclear. I will assume that you want to find all strings of the form DQ [anything but DQ or \DQ]* DQ.

The regex for this `/"([^"\\\\]|\\\\"|\\\\[^"])*"/g`

Answer (score 0):

You could also get away with this simpler guy:

```
/("(\\"|[^"])+")/g
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/eMN2S/